# Chance of a good subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S_1,S_2$ be sets of size $n$ with distinct elements. Form the set $S$ by picking $4k$ elements uniformly at random from $S_1\bigcup S_2$ $(k\leq n/2)$. $S$ is a good subset if it contains at least $k$ elements from each of $S_1$ and $S_2$. Is it true that $S$ is a good subset with probability $1-c_1\exp(-c_2k)$ for some absolute constants $c_1,c_2>0$ (independent of $n$)?

Comment: Yes. Hypergeometric (what you have here) is more concentrated than Binomial and you can apply Chernoff/Hoeffding exponential concentration bounds to the binomial.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a link for this?

Comment: Looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Tail_Bounds does the job. Thanks for telling me the keyword: Hypergeometric!

Comment: You are welcome. Just notice that these bounds come from the [Binomial distribution bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds) and that directly dealing with Hypergeometric is a bit messy (apart from easy correction for the variance (compared to the binomial)) because the draws are negatively correlated.